# jQuery Address + $.ajax not displaying content

Tags: jquery, ajax, deep-linking, jquery-address

I'm trying to implement the jQuery Address plugin in my project.

I'm following the Asual example of the [Crawling](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/crawling/) implementation (i.e. hashbangs).

My javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.address.init(function(event) {
        // Initializes plugin support for links
        $('a:not([href^=http])').address();

        var handler = function(data) {
            $('.content').html($('#content', data).html()).parent().show();
            $.address.title(/>([^<]*)<\/title/.exec(data)[1]);
        };

        // Loads the page content and inserts it into the content area
        $.ajax({
            url: '/index.php?ACT=87&action=shows&_escaped_fragment_=' + encodeURIComponent(event.value),
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                handler(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                handler(data);
            },
            contentType: 'text/html'
        });
    });
</script>
```

The $.ajax() call is requesting a dummy html page I created:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html>
    <head><title>testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="content">test</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm sending this HTML page with the `text/html` content type.

The request is executing successfully, and the handler anonymous function is getting the entire page data, but the `$('.content).html()` command isn't working. When I do `alert($('#content', data).html());`, I get `null`, and nothing happens. No errors, but no content either.

I'm pretty much at my wits end at this point... any recommendations?

**Edit:** To clarify, the problem isn't with the request itself, nor a URL, nor a browser security issue. I'm simply unable to select and display data from my request on the page.

To make matters worse, if I simply replace the $.ajax() url with that of a page that I know doesn't exist (i.e. a 404 page), it parses and displays my 404 message just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. I replaced the $.ajax() call with the following:

```
$('.content').load('/index.php?ACT=87&action=shows&_escaped_fragment_=' + encodeURIComponent(event.value) +' #content');
```

Would still be interested to know if anybody could tell me what I was doing wrong with $.ajax().

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be that your use of the selector context.

```
$('#content', data)
```

This doesn't work because `data` is not a jQuery object, it is just HTML.

Three options I can think of:

1)

```
//not sure if you can just wrap data within the selector so putting it in a variable
var myhtml = $(data);
$('#content', myhtml)
```

2) Have your dummy html page only be that #content div. You don't need to have a full page if you're just getting if via ajax.

3) Try to restructure your code to use the [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function, which allows you to specify a selector in order to just get a specific piece of content from the loaded file
`$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');`

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax is fine.

I couldn't get any of the other answers to work with JSFiddle, but this works. I doubt its the best way to go about it though:

```
var handler = function(data) {
    // Create jQuery object with received data
    var $content = $('<div></div>').html(data); 

    // Get the html that you wanted   
    var theHtml = $('#content', $content).html();

    // Place content into page proper
    $('.content').html(theHtml).parent().show();

    // Rest of function...
}
```

Here it is all on one line if you're one of those masochistic types:

```
$('.content').html($('#content', $('<div></div>').html(data)).html()).parent().show();
```